# Consequences resulting from Yitang Zhang's latest claimed results on Landau-Siegel zeros

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, landau-siegel-zeros

Very recently, Yitang Zhang just gave a (virtual) [talk](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/ymlacu/professor_yitang_zhangs_latest_paper_about_the/) about his work on Landau-Siegel zeros at Shandong University on the 5th of November's morning in China. He will also give a talk on 8th November at Peking University.

The 111-page [preprint](https://pan.baidu.com/s/1GM61FrLynSfpSn67SoaHow?pwd=1105) now can be found on the internet, and it seems this version will be published on arXiv soon. (UPDATE: now it's [on arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.02515).)

This paper shows that for a real primitive character $\chi$ to the modulus $D$,
$$ L(1, \chi) > c_{1}(\log D)^{-2022} $$
where $c_{1} > 0$ is an absolute, effectively computable constant.

Assuming this result is correct, what are some significant number theoretical consequences that would follow?

For example, what would be the impact on PNT error estimates, arithmetic progressions, and other related problems?

Comment: The conversation in comments has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140487/discussion-on-question-by-blanco-consequences-resulting-from-yitang-zhangs-late). At this point comments are not really adding to helping address the question, we have two good answers that do.

Comment: Here are Yitang Zhang’s [comments](https://www.cantorsparadise.com/translated-comments-by-yitang-zhang-on-landau-siegel-mathematics-and-life-358eeefbb0e) on the Landau-Siegel Zeros Conjecture.

Comment: Maybe [this our new](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1140/epjp/s13360-024-05000-w) paper can be considered as another consequence resulting from Yitang Zhang's latest results.

Answer (score 58):

It has significant implications on the error term of the PNT for arithmetic progressions.

### PNT and Siegel-Walfisz theorem

Let $\psi(x;q,a)$ be the sum of $\Lambda(n)$ over $n\le x$ and $n\equiv a\pmod q$. Then the PNT states that for fixed $q$ there is

$$
\psi(x;q,a)\sim{x\over\varphi(q)}.\tag1
$$

When $q$ is not fixed, Page (1935) proved the following general result:

**Theorem 1 (Page):** *There exists some absolute and effective $c_0>0$ such that for all $(a,q)=1$:*

$$
\psi(x;q,a)={x\over\varphi(q)}-\color{blue}{{\chi(a)x^\beta}\over\varphi(q)\beta}+O\{xe^{-c_0\sqrt{\log x}}\},\tag2
$$

*where $\chi$ denotes the exceptional character and $\beta$ denotes the Siegel zero. The blue term would be dropped if there are no exceptional characters modulo $q$.*

To unify the error terms, we require a result due to Siegel (1935):

**Theorem 2 (Siegel):** *For all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists some $A_\varepsilon>0$ such that $1-\beta>A_\varepsilon q^{-\varepsilon}$.*

Plugging this result into the blue term of (2), we have

$$
x^\beta\ll x e^{-A_\varepsilon q^{-\varepsilon}\log x}.
$$

If $q\le(\log x)^{2/\varepsilon}$, then the right hand side becomes $\ll xe^{-A_\varepsilon\sqrt{\log x}}$. Combining this with (2) gives us the result of Walfisz (1936):

**Theorem 3 (Siegel-Walfisz):** *For any $M>0$ there exists some $C_M$ such that for all $q\le(\log x)^M$ and $(a,q)=1$ there is*

$$
\psi(x;q,a)={x\over\varphi(q)}+O\{e^{-C_M\sqrt{\log x}}\},\tag3
$$

*where the O-constant is absolute.*

Due to the drawback in the proof of Siegel's theorem, $A_\varepsilon$ and $C_M$ are not effectively computable.

### Improvements due to Zhang

However, we can significantly obtain a stronger and effective improvement of Siegel-Walfisz theorem if Zhang's result is used. That is

**Theorem 4 (Zhang):** *There exists $A>0$ and effective $C_1>0$ such that $L(1,\chi)>C_1(\log q)^{-A}$.*

> Zhang proved this result for $A=2022$, but I choose not to plug it in for generality.

Let $\beta$ be the rightmost real zero of $L(s,\chi)$ for some real $\chi$ modulo $q$ such that $1-\beta\gg(\log q)^{-1}$. Then it follows from the mean value theorem that there exists some $1-\beta<\sigma<1$ such that $1-\beta=L(1,\chi)/L'(\sigma,\chi)$. Applying the classical bound $L'(\sigma,\chi)=O(\log^2q)$ and Zhang's result gives us the zero-free region that

$$
1-\beta>C_2(\log q)^{-A-2},
$$

where $C_2>0$ is effectively computable, which indicates that the blue term in (2) is dominated by

$$
x^\beta\ll xe^{-C_2(\log x)(\log q)^{-A-2}}.
$$

If $(\log q)^{A+2}\le\sqrt{\log x}$, then the right hand side becomes $\ll xe^{-C_2\sqrt{\log x}}$, which allows Theorem 1 to be improved significantly:

**Theorem 5:** *Let $A$ be as in Theorem 4. There exists some absolute $c_0>0$ such that for all $q\le e^{(\log x)^{1/(2A+4)}}$ and $(a,q)=1$, we have*

$$
\psi(x;q,a)={x\over\varphi(q)}+O\{e^{-c_0\sqrt{\log x}}\}.\tag4
$$

### Asymptotic formulas valid for all $q\ge1$.

Although Theorem 5 is much stronger than Theorem 3, it is difficult to compare them to Theorem 1 without the blue term, so this section is dedicated to deduce asymptotic formula valid for all $q\ge1$ and $(a,q)=1$ so that a better comparison can be made.

Since $\Lambda(n)\le\log n$, we know trivially that

$$
\psi(x;q,a)\le\sum_{\substack{n\le x\\n\equiv a(q)}}\log x\ll{x\log x\over q}.
$$

Combining this with (3), we see that Theorem 3 indicates that

$$
\psi(x;q,a)={x\over\varphi(q)}+O_N\{x(\log x)^{-N}\}\quad(N>0).\tag5
$$

If the trivial upper bound is juxtaposed with (4), then we see that there exists some absolute and effective $c_0>0$ such that

$$
\psi(x;q,a)={x\over\varphi(q)}+O\{xe^{-c_0(\log x)^{1/(2A+4)}}\},
$$

which has a substantially better error term than (5).

Comment: See also the Wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siegel%E2%80%93Walfisz_theorem

Comment: How did you arrive at estimate (5)?

Comment: When $q\ge(\log x)^{N+1}$, it follows from $\varphi(q)\gg q/\log\log q$ that $x/\varphi(q)\ll x/(\log x)^N$. When $q\le(\log x)^{N+1}$, we see that (3)'s error term is $\ll x/(\log x)^N$. Therefore, combining both cases gives us (5).

Answer (score 51):

There will be many important consequences of Zhang's result, if correct.  One specific result is that it will reduce one of the last open problem from the era of Gauss and Euler to a finite amount of computation, namely the classification of discriminants of binary quadratic forms with one class per genus.  The congruence class of a prime number $p$ modulo $d$ determines which form of discriminant $-d<0$ represents $p$  if and only if there is one class per genus.

Such discriminants which are congruent to $0$ modulo $4$ are  Euler's *numeri idonei* or idoneal numbers.  Euler expected there would be infinitely many such discriminants.  [**Edit**: Apparently I'm mis-remembering this.  See the remarks of KConrad below.] It was Gauss who conjectured  that the only such discriminants are the 65 examples (not necessarily fundamental) known to Euler.  There are also 65 known fundamental discriminants (not necessarily even) with one class per genus.  The existence of a 66th is still an open problem.  By genus theory we know that for discriminants with one class per genus, the class group satisfies
$$
C(-d)\cong \left(\mathbb Z/2\right)^{g-1},
$$
where $g$ is the number of prime divisors of $d$.  Obviously $d$ is bigger than the absolute value of the smallest fundamental discriminant with $g$ prime divisors,
$$
d_g\overset{\text{def.}}=3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot7\cdots p_g.
$$
From lower bounds on the size of $p_g$, the $g$-th prime, and on $\theta(x)=\sum_{p\leq x}\log(p)$, one can show that
$$
d_g>g^g.
$$
Since $
2^{g-1} \ll \sqrt{g^g}, 
$
lower bounds for the class number which we expect to be true rule out the possibility for one class per genus for large $g$.

In 1973, Peter Weinberger showed that on GRH, no fundamental discriminant $-d<-5460$ has one class per genus, and unconditionally there is at most one more such $d$.

In contrast, Oesterle explicitly observed that the lower bound due to Goldfeld-Gross-Zagier  is not strong enough to finish the classification of discriminants with one class per genus:
$
\log(g^g) $ is $\ll 2^{g-1}
$.
Iwaniec and Kowalski observed that even the full strength of the Birch Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture, "the best effective lower bounds which current technology allows us to hope for"  would not suffice, as $ \log(g^g)^r$ is $\ll 2^{g-1}$  for any $r$.  In fact, the outlook is still more bleak:  Watkins observed that if the discriminant $-d$ is divisible by all the primes up to $(\log\log d)^3$ (as $d_g$ certainly is), the product over primes dividing $d$ in the Goldfeld-Gross-Zagier lower bound is so small the resulting bound is worse than the trivial bound.

If the implied constant is made explicit, Zhang's result would eliminate the possibility of one class per genus for discriminants above some bound.  For example, neglecting the constant, the lower bound is discriminants with more than 6007 prime divisors.  This works out to $d>3\cdot 10^{25734}$.

Comment: Are you sure Euler expected infinitely many after his work on such numbers? Perhaps initially  he thought these numbers would provide him with a method of checking primality of some large numbers for that time, but I think he was shocked to find no more examples bigger than 1848 and I don’t believe he continued to expect such numbers should keep appearing.

Comment: In Kani's survey on idoneal numbers https://www.mast.queensu.ca/~kani/papers/idoneal-f.pdf he quotes from Euler about there probably being finitely many: "... multo magis verisimillimum videtur, post hunc terminum nullos praetera existere" (it seems much more likely that after this there are no more). After that, Euler wrote  "id quod eo magis est natatu dignum, quod nulla adhuc in Analysi talis numerorum series occurrit, quae finito tantum terminorum numero constaret" (which is all the more worthy of praise, since no such series of numbers has occurred in Analysis having finitely many terms).

Comment: @KConrad I borrowed some of this answer from an expository paper I wrote many years ago.  I don't recall where I got the Euler remark from, so I'll defer to you.

Comment: Why do you call this “the last open problem from the era of Gauss and Euler”? The Euler brick problem, the Goldbach conjecture and Legendre’s conjecture are all open.

Comment: @MattF. I edited to 'one of the last'. But in my opinion, the problems you mention are one-offs and not central.  The genius of what Gauss did, building on the work of Euler, created number theory as a cohesive subject.