# Did Zhang weaken the constant in his Landau-Siegel zero paper to get the current year?

Tags: nt.number-theory

[Zhang 2022](https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.02515) proves a somewhat suspicious formula:

$$L(1,\chi) \gg (\log D)^{-2022}$$

This raises the obvious-but-frivolous question: did he intentionally weaken the constant to get the current year?

Comment: You might want to look at this short twitter thread: https://mobile.twitter.com/mattecapu/status/1588846559772352512. Indeed, it seems clear that 2022 was just an arbitrary-ish number, and establishing the qualitative behavior of the inequality was more important than obtaining the sharpest possible results.

Comment: @SamHopkins: Thank you!  That seems like a positive answer if it holds up.

Comment: (Also, in case it confuses anyone, David Roberts's first tweet there is slightly wrong: as explained in answers to https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433949/, this result would improve the error term in the Prime Number Theorem in Arithmetic Progressions, but has no bearing on the usual PNT itself...)

Comment: You are forgetting about one possibility: maybe he *strengthened* the constant to get the current year :-)

Comment: ^ This would indeed make the joke much cooler.

Comment: Does anyone know any other public venues where Zhang's preprint is being discussed?

Comment: Yes, my apologies about the blooper!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

According to himself, yes. The following is a link to some of his comments that he posted on a Chinese forum.
https://www.zhihu.com/question/564799818/answer/2752632822

> Regarding the question of whether the fixed power of logD , which is taken for many parameters in the paper, is to get the number 2022, in terms of the Landau-Siegel zero itself, that should be a power of logD, and the conjectured should actually be -1. My method can lead to an exponent of negative several hundred which I did not calculate carefully, yet I can guarantee -2022. Since this year is 2022, I chose it casually. Often people do this kind of thing, so this also does not have any special meaning, just like the previous 70 million (in the bounded gaps between primes paper).

Comment: Unfortunate that this falsifies @Carl-Fredrik Nyberg Brodda's alternative theory in the comments.

Comment: Bill Johnson a **New contributor**? In good old times he had his own tag **ask-johnson**.

Comment: Let us all be glad he didn't choose "420"