# Philosophy behind Zhang's 2022 preprint on the Landau–Siegel zero

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, landau-siegel-zeros

Now that a week has passed since Zhang posted his preprint [Discrete mean estimates and the Landau–Siegel zero](https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.02515) on the arXiv, I'm wondering if someone can give a high-level overview of his strategy.  In more detail: the paper first claims to show that an abnormally small value for the $L$-function at $s=1$ (or equivalently, a zero close to $s=1$), will influence the zeros of other $L$-functions, forcing them to lie on the critical line (which is expected) and to be very regularly spaced (which definitely is not expected).  This part of the paper has a long history, going under the name of the Deuring–Heilbronn phenomenon.  Many researchers claimed results in this direction in conference papers, including Montgomery (Zhang's reference [17]) and Heath-Brown (Zhang's [13]).  Full proofs were obtained by Conrey and Iwaniec (‘[Spacing of zeros of Hecke L-functions and the class number problem](https://doi.org/10.4064/aa103-3-5)’, Acta Arith. 103 (2002), no. 3, 259–312).  Mark Watkins subsequently published ‘[Comments on Deuring's zero-spacing phenomenon](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2020.07.010)’, J. Number Theory 218 (2021), 1–43.

As far as I can see, what Zhang claims in this part is similar to the Conrey–Iwaniec result, lower bounding the $L$-function value by a power of logarithm under a hypothesis on the spacing of zeros.  (If I've missed something, let me know.)

The rest of Zhang's paper claims to show that this regular spacing does not happen.  Ruling out this ‘Alternative Hypothesis’ has been a goal in analytic number theory for decades, and despite the work of many (Montgomery for test functions with restricted support, Katz–Sarnak for the function field analog, Odlyzko and Rubinstein on numerical data for the zeros of the zeta function and Dirichlet $L$-functions, respectively), no one has been able to rule out this regular spacing.  (For specific values of the discriminant, specific spacing of numerically computed zeros has had applications since Stark's 1964 UC Berkeley PhD thesis "On the tenth complex quadratic field with class-number one"

Zhang gives only a few hints of the strategy.  In the abstract, “by evaluating certain discrete means of the large sieve type, a contradiction can be obtained….”

At the bottom of page 8 and top of page 9 “This is analogous to the results of Conrey, Iwaniec, and Soundararajan [5] and [6].  However, it seems that such a choice … is not good enough for our purpose.  … instead, a variant of the argument will be adopted.”

What is it he is trying to do?

Comment: Other MO questions about this work: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434287 https://mathoverflow.net/questions/434150 https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433949 https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131221. It's obviously exciting but we may be getting out over our skis in terms of the volume of speculation on this site about this announcement.

Comment: You might also be interested in this blog comment from Terry Tao about how certain misprints in the preprint make it hard(er) to evaluate: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2021/09/15/the-hardy-littlewood-chowla-conjecture-in-the-presence-of-a-siegel-zero/comment-page-1/#comment-660236

Comment: Is that supposed to be "that this regular spacing *does* happen" in the first sentence of the third paragraph?

Comment: @Buzz No, it's correct as written. Siegel zero implies regular spacing, which is something we don't expect to be true, and by proving the spacing is not regular we show Siegel zero (or whatever "bad" zeros we concern here) cannot exist.

Comment: @Buzz No.  We expect the zeros to be distributed like the eigenvalues of random matrices.  This 'GUE hypothesis' is in contrast to the 'Alternative hypothesis' regular spacing caused (in some sense) by the Landau-Siegel zero.

Comment: I would advise that public discussion of the preprint be postponed until there is reasonable consensus on the correctness of the manuscript (after the issues already located have been addressed by Yitang).  I understand the excitement about this potentially significant result, but the slow, careful process of verifying (a hopefully forthcoming revision of) the manuscript still needs to be done, and too much premature public discussion of the preprint could in fact distract from and interfere with this necessary step.  Check back in a month or so.

Comment: @TerryTao Why? I agree with your comment if this post and comment thread were people merely speculating about the correctness of the argument. This question is asking about the approach of the preprint. In fact, I think this will make the verification process easier.

Comment: The main thing that would make the verification process easier is the release of a carefully revised and proofread version of the manuscript by Yitang.  For this, I believe it would be more efficacious if questions and concerns about the paper are communicated to Yitang by private channels, rather than public forums such as MathOverflow, which Yitang has not shown much prior interest in engaging with.

Comment: Zhang himself gave a [Chinese talk](https://www.bilibili.com/video/BV1eP4y127XG/?spm_id_from=333.337.search-card.all.click) on Nov 8 to explain his motivation. Hopefully it helps somebody.

Comment: There are also some blog-posts (in particular one written by "Xinzhiyuan") on Zhihu summarizing one of Zhang's recent talks: https://www.zhihu.com/question/564799818, or translated: https://www-zhihu-com.translate.goog/question/564799818?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en&_x_tr_pto=wapp

Comment: There's an official translated version of some of Zhang's comments here: https://www.cantorsparadise.com/translated-comments-by-yitang-zhang-on-landau-siegel-mathematics-and-life-358eeefbb0e

Comment: Do we now know better whether Zhang's idea works or not?

Comment: He gave a talk at Harvard https://mathpicture.fas.harvard.edu/event/seminar-yitang-zhang-university-california-santa-barbara and as far as I could follow the work is still unfinished.

Comment: It was  *Non-positive sequences in analytic number theory and the Landau-Siegel zero*
Abstract:  A number of problems in analytic number theory can be reduced to showing that some related sequences are non-positive. In this direction a typical treatment is based on the idea of the $\Lambda^2$-sieve due to Selberg. We introduce a new approach that may find application to the Landau-Siegel zero problem.

Comment: The link to Stark's PhD thesis seems to be broken for me, possibly because of the proxy URL.

Comment: @TheAmplitwist You can get Stark's thesis via Interlibrary Loan from UC Berkeley.  I can no longer find a copy online.  (It's interesting reading.)