# Contribution of Yitang Zhang latest results if correct to correlation conjecture of H. L. Montgomery?

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-hypothesis, prime-gaps, landau-siegel-zeros

There are some  integrals related to the celebrated pair correlation conjecture of H. L. Montgomery. One of them is the integral introduced by Selberg related to estimating the variance of primes in short intervals: I read the last interesting paper of [Yitang Zhang](https://arxiv.org/abs/2211.02515) and it seems to me that the paper discusses the statistical distribution of Landau-Siegel zeros and primes as well. In the same time the correlation conjecture of H. L. Montgomery deals with estimation of the variance of primes.

> **My Question is**: assuming Yitang Zhang latest results correct, to what extent these results would contribute to correlation conjecture of H. L. Montgomery?

**Note**: I ask kindly  community  to add tag for Yitang Zhang results or Yitang Zhang theorem.

Comment: [Related Q&A](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/433949/consequences-resulting-from-yitang-zhangs-latest-claimed-results-on-landau-sieg). I'm not sure if anyone's directly addressed your query there, but a fair amount of discussion about the consequences of the result has already been had and may be ongoing.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy, Thanks for the link ,I already checked these questions but seems to me some consequences were adressed to be in general but here i asked for specific contribution which is not montioned there,namely,connection to HL Montgomery

Comment: Note that pair correlation has been established unconditionally in a recent preprint by Suriajaya et al.

Comment: The considered preprint: https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.04799